# Can I use native app resources files inside a flutter module added to native app?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-add-to-app

I have a native android app where some of my views are Flutter views added to my native app through Flutter add-to-app feature. In my native app I have a plethora of dimensions, colors and strings defined on xml resource files which are used by my native classes and views.

I would like to use these same resources inside my flutter views, without having to copy the files into my flutter module repository (since I would have to maintain both copies every time I needed to change something)